# java slack bot integration join channel tag

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a java app that acts like slack bot and sends text messages to slack channel. But, if I send 'Please join #mysuperchannel', the #mysuperchannel is not highlighted as a link which I can join that channel in one click. It's just a text. What should  I use to get this #mysuperchannel word be highlighted and clickable in slack chat window? Sth like a tag or mark or anything else to let it know I want to get this word like a reference to the channel it represents.   Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Slack markup language to make the channel name linkable.

Here is syntax for linking a channel: `<#C12345678|name>`. Just put that in the text you are sending to the Slack channel.

- `C12345678` is the ID of the channel you want to
  link.
- `name` is just a text that will appear as label for the link

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users) for full documentation including more examples.

Comment: thanks, but when I paste this string nothing happens, it's just text, how to do that? I expect I insert text and it converts to link, no?

Comment: It will work. make sure you have the correct ID for the channel you want people to join. Also, if you are sending your request to Slack by GET make sure that all special chars <, #, |, > are encoded or http.

Comment: And yes. you insert the markup in your normal text that you are sending to Slack.

Comment: I am trying to send this message in slack windows client. Insert correct channel id, name and just text, no link

Comment: hmm. you did not say that in your question. Using links to channel only works if you send text using a webhook or the Slack API

Comment: oh sorry for that, I was sure there's no difference how will I send it. Anyway it works, thanks for your help